# Input select box value and value display on text box for update

Tags: javascript, html

I have select box and input box and i want to when i am select any value then it's show on text for update..

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: Do you mean to copy the value from the select box to the input box when it changes?

Comment: i mean selected value are look on text box (php code) for update selected value

Comment: mind putting more efforts into rephrasing your question? I am not native (which usually helps dealing with non grammar English) but I got no clue what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check This http://jsfiddle.net/kxqJN/
When A User Select A Value In Drop Down That Value Will Be Visible In The Text Box

This Done By A Simple `JQuery`

Below Is `HTML`

```
<select id="data">
 <option value="One">One</option>
 <option value="Tow">Tow</option>
 <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>    
<input type="text" id="dataval" />
```

Below Is `Jquery`

```
$("#data").change(function(){
   var item = $(this).val();        
   $("#dataval").val(item);
});
```

Comment: can you post your source here